# How to preserve Linq2SQL OR between conditions?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression-trees

Lets say we need to select two sets from a table: "Things"

```
var GradeA = db.Things.Where(t=>  condition1);
var GradeB = db.Things.Where(t=> !condition1 && condition2);
var DesiredList = GradeA.union(GradeB);
```

alternatively, we need to write a single statement to avoid `union` cost:

```
var DesiredList = db.Things.Where(t=> condtion1 || (!condition1 && condition2));
```

the problem is query optimizer seems to trim the expression to ***condition2*** only.

How to preserve the priority between ***condition1*** and ***condition2***

a real life example workaround is :

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets only first BookTag for each tag word, chooses the one of this user (if exists).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="book"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IQueryable<BookTag> UniqueByTags(this IQueryable<BookTag> bookTags, User user)
{
    return bookTags.GroupBy(BT => BT.TagId)
        .Select(g => g.Any(bt => bt.UserId == user.Id) ? 
            new BookTag() { User = user, Tag = g.First().Tag, Book = bookTags.First().Book } : 
            new BookTag() {User = g.First().User, Tag = g.First().Tag, Book = bookTags.First().Book}
            );
}
```

### Edit:

Example is getting Auto-Complete list:

- input: `str`
- output: things that start with `str` and things that contain `str` (no duplicates)

---

Another Example:
Selecting `ThingTags` which have 3 properties:

- `ThingID`
- `UserID`
- `TagID`

we want to select only one `ThingTag` for each `TagID` under condition that we select the one with `UserID` equals parameter if **exists**, otherwise select first `ThingTag` for that `TagID`.

Still with me ? hope so :)

---

Comment: Your first example is simply expressed as "things that contain str" (because anything starting with str also contains str). Please could you show the SQL generated by my suggestion, and an example of where that doesn't do what you want?

Comment: The idea is to check for the StartsWith() condition first, then the contains() condition, I will try to analyze sql generated by you suggestion (but no promises :D), Thanks Jon

Comment: @Ahmed: But my point is that the StartsWith test is pointless, as Contains will pick up anything that starts with the string anyway.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That's technically true, but the whole point is about condition priority, let's say you wanna get first matching word but with priority to the StartsWith() ... they aren't the same. Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean "but with priority"? SQL queries don't return rows in the order that they matched the predicate(s) - that is what ORDER BY is for...? In fact, **explicitly** the engine *has* to return them in the same sequence **no matter** how it internally decides to execute the query.

Comment: You need to post your actual code, your actual dataset and the actual required output.  The 'priority' part of your question does not make any sense at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason for not writing this:

```
var DesiredList = db.Things.Where(t=> condition1 || condition2);
```

That's logically the same set of elements, after all. As it's a simpler expression, it's more likely that the query generator will get it right. Having said that, I'm surprised it's getting it wrong. Do you have a complete example you could provide?

Comment: @Jon - you might want to double check my thinking, but it looks like he's talking about doing an XOR rather than a simple OR. He doesn't want results when BOTH conditions are true.

Comment: @Justin - That may be the intent, but based on the question, if condition 1 and condition 2 are true, the first part of the OR evaluates true and gets an overall true, so it's logically equivalent.

Comment: @Justin: Nick's logic was exactly what I had in mind. Note that due to shortcircuiting, the *C#* code would only evaluate `condition2` if `condition1` was false anyway. Quite what that means for the generated SQL, I'm not sure.

Comment: It depends where (in C# or in SQL Server) this is getting handled, C# has deterministic short-circuiting, but SQL does not.  Also, the validity of the logical transform (A || (!A && B)) ==> (A || B) is dependent on whether NULL results are possible and taken into account, because in 3-valued logic, (A || !A) is *not* a tautology.

Comment: Good point about the three-valued logic. Hopefully Ahmed will post what happened when he tried this idea at some point...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to do an XOR (Exclusive or) rather than a regular OR between your two conditions (in other words, you want the items that meet the requirements of only one OR the other...not both).

I'm not positive about LINQ to SQL, but I know LINQ to Objects supports the XOR...so you can give it a shot. Here's the syntax:

```
var DesiredList = db.Things.Where(t => condition1 ^ condition2);
```

Comment: this would select a Thing given condition1 true while condition2 false, I want to disregard condition2 when condition1 is satisfied

Answer (score 0):

To take the example literally, you could perform the combination in the question by building an `Expression` on the fly:

```
    static IQueryable<T> WhereXElseY<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateA,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateB)
    {
        var condA = predicateA.Body;
        var param = predicateA.Parameters[0];

        var body = Expression.OrElse(
            condA,
            Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.Not(condA),
                Expression.Invoke(
                    predicateB, param)));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            body, param);
        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
```

However, while this may work with LINQ-to-SQL, it won't work with EF since EF sadly hates `Expression.Invoke`. But as Jon notes; if you are sending this down to a database backend, the priority is irrelevant and you might as well go with the logically equivalent `condition1 || condition2`. You can combine expressions something like:

```
    static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query,
        params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] predicates)
    {
        if (predicates == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicates");
        if (predicates.Length == 0) return query.Where(x => false);
        if (predicates.Length == 1) return query.Where(predicates[0]);

        var param = predicates[0].Parameters[0];
        var body = predicates[0].Body;
        for (int i = 1; i < predicates.Length; i++)
        {
            body = Expression.OrElse(
                body, Expression.Invoke(predicates[i], param));
        }
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
```

If I've missed the point, please clarify...

Comment: Thanks Marc ! but I'd like to ask, does it make any difference if I build the expression in code or as lambda ? I think query optimizer will work on it and we get the same results ?

Comment: In general (and in theory) the result would be the same; this answer relates to a given scenario of usage - but if you *can* write it all as a simple one-liner, then do that.

Comment: this means we wont get a different result, hence no progress :(

Comment: It shouldn't do; care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** I would really re-check your original code for the conditions, while its possible there is a bug in the query optimizer its more likely there was a bug on the expression used and it really didn't represent the below:

> var DesiredList = db.Things.Where(t=> condition1 || (!condition1 && condition2));
>
> the problem is query optimizer seems
>   to trim the expression to condition2
>   only.

That should really give you the ones that match condition1 regardless of condition2 ... and ones that don't match condition1 and match condition2. Instead condition2 alone is not equivalent because that leaves out records that only match condition1.

JS version of just (condition1 || condition2) is equivalent to the quoted expression above, as when u are matching condition1 you are already matching both condition2 and !condition2 so you are already including condition2 for both condition1 and !condition1 cases. If this doesn't match what you intended with the queries, is then clearer that's not an issue with the optimizer but with the original expressions.

You would only need the full expressions if you were joining 2 results with a Concat instead of Union, as that would mean you would end up with results matching in both expressions ... and then you would have repeated results. But in contrast, the Where is evaluated per row, so you don't have those concerns in there.

---

**Second:** From the code sample, I think what you are facing is less direct of what you are going after in your question. You mentioned you are getting the first tag, but what you are really doing can be seen in this re-written version:

```
public static IQueryable<BookTag> UniqueByTags(this IQueryable<BookTag> bookTags, User user)
{
    return bookTags.GroupBy(BT => BT.TagId)
        .Select(g => new BookTag() { 
             User = g.Any(bt => bt.UserId == user.Id) ? user : g.First().User,
             Tag = g.First().Tag, Book = bookTags.First().Book 
        });
}
```

What's mentioned in the comment seems more like:

```
public static IQueryable<BookTag> UniqueByTags(this IQueryable<BookTag> bookTags, User user)
{
    return bookTags.GroupBy(BT => BT.TagId)
        .Select(g => g.Any(bt => bt.UserId == user.Id) ? 
            g.First(bt=>bt.UserId == user.Id) : 
            g.First()
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy ! For the second part of your answer, I don't really think these re-writes are a good idea, because I want ONLY ONE query to be executed but you use First(bt=>bt.UserId == user.Id) again after you already executed the ANY()... which is not the same performance as the originally intended query